# http server response using sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, http, server

My sockets server is receiving a GET request for an image, the image is 2MB so it doesn't fit in a single send(), this is what I am sending in the first send():

```
std::stringstream wsss;
wsss << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" 
     << "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
     << "Content-Type: image/x-icon\r\n"
     << "Content-Length: " << imageSize << "\r\n"
     << "\r\n";
wsss.write(imageData, imageSize);
```

Does every subsequent send() of this image needs the header fields?
I am sending a .ico image, are the header fields correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the image is 2MB so it doesn't fit in a single send()

`send()` is not guaranteed to send as many bytes as you ask it to send. It *can* send fewer bytes.  Its return value tells you how many bytes it actually accepted for sending.  So you should call `send()` in a loop until all bytes have been accepted.  If you move this loop into its own reusable function, that will also allow you to send the icon data without having to first copy it into the `std::stringstream`.

Try something like this:

```
int sendData(int sckt, void *data, int datalen)
{
    unsigned char *pdata = (unsigned char *) data;
    int numSent;

    // send() can send fewer bytes than requested,
    // so call it in a loop until the specified data
    // has been sent in full...

    while (datalen > 0) {
      numSent = send(sckt, pdata, datalen, 0);
      if (numSent == -1) return -1;
      pdata += numSent;
      datalen -= numSent;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
std::stringstream wsss;
wsss << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" 
     << "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
     << "Content-Type: image/x-icon\r\n"
     << "Content-Length: " << imageSize << "\r\n"
     << "\r\n";

// do not append the image data to the stringstream...
//wsss.write(imageData, imageSize);

// send the headers first...
std::string headers = wsss.str();
int res = sendData(TheSocket, headers.c_str(), headers.size());
if (res == -1) ...

// now send the image data...
res = sendData(TheSocket, imageData, imageSize);
if (res == -1) ...
```

> Does every subsequent send() of this image needs the header fields?

Every *HTTP response* to every *HTTP request* for the same image needs to send the same headers<sup>1</sup>. But every `send()` for *any particular response* does not need to repeat the headers, they only need to be sent once.  Just keep sending whatever bytes have not been sent yet. That is why you have to pay attention to the return value of `send()` so you know how many bytes have been sent so far and how many bytes are still need to be sent.

> I am sending a .ico image, are the header fields correct?

In general, yes<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>: **assuming** that either:

1. the client sent an HTTP 1.1 request without a `Connection: close` request header.
2. the client sent an HTTP 1.0 request with a `Connection: keep-alive` request header.

Otherwise, your `Connection: keep-alive` header would be erroneous, you should be sending a `Connection: close` header instead, and then close the socket after sending the complete response.

Comment: you put the send() inside a loop but shouldn't it be better to send() only when you get a request?... I am not sure but I think browsers keep sending a GET request if they didn't receive the whole image.

Comment: @Wusevari: Look at my example again more carefully. I am not sending a response multiple times. There is only *one* response being sent (and presumably only in response to a request, since you did not show all of your server code). The response is being sent in two separate pieces (headers and image). The code is looping through the first part (headers) until fully sent, then looping through the second part (image) until fully sent, and then it stops sending (until the next request is received).

Comment: My comment was not clear enough. Let's say the image is 1TB, in this case the function sendData() will stay alive for very long time, so shouldn't it be better to just send() the rest of the remaining data only when the browser request it?(this method will only work if browsers keep sending a GET request until they finish getting all the image data, and I am not sure if browsers really do this).

Comment: You clearly do not understand how the HTTP protocol actually works, or how browsers request data. Start by reading [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616). A browser will not know how large the image actually is until the server starts sending the response (and even then, it might still not know, if the server chooses to send it in `chunked` format - see [RFC 2616 Section 3.6.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.6.1)). The browser will happily sit there waiting for the entire image to be received, no matter how large it is...

Comment: ... Once a response has begun, the browser keeps reading until the response is finished, however long it takes. The server is responsible for sending the entire image from start to end in a single response, unless the browser requests otherwise.  The browser *can* request a resource in pieces (via a `Range` request header - see [RFC 2616 Section 14.35](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.35)), but it will not usually do that in most cases. Usually only when downloading a file to the user's hard drive, and even then usually only to resume a previously-broken download.

Comment: I am gonna test this hypothesis, browser sends a GET request for an image then it receives a chunk of the requested data, it finds that this first chunk has a "Content-Length:" and it figures out that the chunk of data received is not the full data so it sends a GET request again. Gona report back with results.

Comment: @Wusevari: I **guarantee** you that is not how a browser operates, so there is no point in testing it.  If a `Content-Length` header is present in the response, the browser will keep reading until it has received the specified number of bytes. HTTP is specifically designed to work this way. The browser determines the length of the response (and thus the length of the requested data) based on rules defined in [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4)...

Comment: ... TCP can't transfer 1TB of data in a single `send()` no matter what. If the icon is 1TB in size, the `Content-Length` will be 1TB, but multiple `send()`/`recv()` calls are required on both sides to actually send/receive 1TB of data.  The browser WILL NOT send multiple `GET` requests to transfer the complete icon. It will send *one* request, receive *one* response for 1TB of data, and will read the full 1TB (assuming the socket connection is not disconnected before the response is finished).

Comment: Stop what you are doing with this code until you have read a good HTTP tutorial.  If you don't understand how HTTP actually works, you can't write effective socket code to process HTTP traffic correctly.

Comment: it will be a bad design too, the send in a loop is bad too, sending every X microseconds will be better

Comment: You clearly do not understand socket programming, either. There is nothing wrong with using `send()` in a loop, especially if the socket is in blocking mode (which it is by default, unless you configure it otherwise).  You don't need to break up sends like you are thinking, unless you have to multiplex multiple socket connections in the same thread. Go find yourself a good socket programming tutorial before you tackle HTTP programming.

Comment: I'm done.  I'm not saying anything further on this matter.

Comment: @Wusevar You are mistaken. This is not 'bad design'. It is how every TCP program works, at least the correct ones. Your assertion that 'sending every X microseconds will be better' is baseless, and betrays zero understanding of TCP/IP or indeed basic I/O. *That is what TCP already does,* more or less, behind the scenes. The task of the application is merely to shift data into TCP's send buffer as quickly as possible, and this is how to do it.